# Calculate the averages of two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to calculate the averages of two grades in two different arrays but I can not access them.

How do I access both the `finalArray1` and `finalArray` values such that I will be able to calculate the averages of both numbers and add them to the array called averages.

I think it is due to the scope of the two arrays. How do I change the program so that I will be able to access the Arrays from anywhere in the program?

```
private Scanner a;

public void openFile() {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        a = new Scanner(new File("IR101.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (a.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(a.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayOne = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayOne);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne));
    int size = arrayOne.length;
    double[] finalArray = new double[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        String word = arrayOne[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray[j] = grade;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray));
}
//ID's and second set of grades

private Scanner b;

public void openFile2() {
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        b = new Scanner(new File("IR102.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (b.hasNextLine()) {
        list2.add(b.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayTwo = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayTwo);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayTwo));
    int size = arrayTwo.length;
    double[] finalArray2 = new double[size];
    for(int j = 0; j<size;j++) {
        String word = arrayTwo[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray2[j] = grade2;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray2));
}
// ID's and names

private Scanner c;

public void openFile3() {
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        c = new Scanner(new File("IRStudents.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (c.hasNextLine()) {
        list3.add(c.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayThree = list3.toArray(new String[list3.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayThree);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayThree));
    int size = arrayThree.length;
    String[] names = new String[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        names[j] = arrayThree[j].substring(6);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}
```

Comment: If all above ar in same file declare all your array before all functions. If they are all in different file then define getter/setter of those arrays.

Comment: Too much code ! However, it is obvious that you have to restructure it completely. Write a single method parsing a given file and use it to parse your different files instead of writing a method for each one, which leads to a lot of duplication

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you simply create ArrayList return types for your "openFile" methods so that it will return the lists for you to manipulate.

I am not sure of your implementation of the code, but this is what it will look like:

---

```js
private Scanner a;

public double[] openFile() {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        a = new Scanner(new File("IR101.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (a.hasNextLine()) {
        list1.add(a.nextLine());

    }
    String[] arrayOne = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayOne);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne));
    int size = arrayOne.length;
    double[] finalArray = new double[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        String word = arrayOne[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray[j] = grade;

    }
 return finalArray;
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray));


}
//ID's and second set of grades


private Scanner b;

public double[] openFile2() {
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        b = new Scanner(new File("IR102.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (b.hasNextLine()) {
        list2.add(b.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayTwo = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayTwo);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayTwo));
    int size = arrayTwo.length;
    double[] finalArray2 = new double[size];
    for(int j = 0; j<size;j++) {
        String word = arrayTwo[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 10);
        double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(newWord);
        finalArray2[j] = grade2;
    }
 return finalArray2;
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray2));

}
// ID's and names

private Scanner c;

public void openFile3() {
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        c = new Scanner(new File("IRStudents.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (c.hasNextLine()) {
        list3.add(c.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayThree = list3.toArray(new String[list3.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayThree);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayThree));
    int size = arrayThree.length;
    String[] names = new String[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        names[j] = arrayThree[j].substring(6);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));

    }

}
```

---

And your implementation of the code would be as such:

---

> UPDATED IMPLEMENTATION

```js
public static void main(String[] args){
 Run r = new Run();
 double[] finalArray = r.openFile();
 double[] finalArray2 = r.openFile2();
}
```

From this point forward you can now manipulate the contents of both arrays and work out your average for them.

I hope I was of some assistance.

Let me know of the outcome!

Comment: Design implications : `java.util.Scanner` should not be declared as an instance member. Abstraction (`java.util.List<E>`) is preferred over its concrete implementation (`java.util.ArrayList<E>`).

Comment: please use ideone.com for JavaCode - this one is for JavaScript

Comment: It shows an error message "Non-static method 'openFile()'cannot be referenced from a static context and the same message is shown for 'openFile2()'.

Comment: @Tiny, yes I understand that. I was just trying to help him quickly :) I will remember that in future.

Comment: @MaxZoom, thank you I was not aware of that. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @jayoguntino... Please have a look at the answer again, I have made the changes that will eliminate the error. Let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: It says 'cannot resolve symbol Run' also says 'Cannot resolve method openFile()' and 'cannot resolve method openFile2()'

Comment: Please replace the "Run" key word with the Name of Your class. So if you class is called "Execute" your code will read "Execute r = new Execute();" ... and you will still say r.openFile(); and r.openFile2();

Comment: Both lines of code declaring the arrays are underlined. The error message says 'Incompatible types. Required: double[] Found : void'

Comment: can you post the actual error here for me please? thanks

Comment: I think I know why that is happening, did you edit the openFile and openFile2 methods like I showed you? It might be that you have not changed the void to double[] ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this snippet is inside a class (lets call it Klass) you could declare your arrays as properties instead of local variables. E.g.:

```
public class Klass {

   private double[] finalArray;
   private double[] finalArray2;

   //...
   //your methods, skipping the finalArray AND finalArray2 declaration
   //...
   public void calculateAvg(){
       //your average alg
       System.out.println("finalArray.length" + this.finalArray.length);
   }
}
```

I would also work with java Collections (java.util.List, for instance).

Hope it helps